# Error al publicar con .netCore 6

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, .net-6.0

la verdad es que no se como resolverlo. Tengo una solución en Visual Studio 2022 Community que al momento de realizar el deploy me aparece un error:

`"dotnet.exe" salió con el código 1.`

Imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el archivo de diagnóstico:

```
16/8/2022 19:40:45
System.AggregateException: Se han producido uno o varios errores. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
---> (Nº de excepción interna 0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.<---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.

===================
```

Busqué información, probe limpiar la solución, correr VS en administrador, probe en hacer el deploy a Folder, pero sigue el mismo error. Hice un chequeo de todos los proyectos dentro de la solución y todos hacen referencia a .net Core 6. Ya no sé que más hacer.

Por último, `dotnet --info`

```
SDK de .NET (que refleje cualquier global.json):
 Version:   6.0.302
 Commit:    c857713418

Entorno de tiempo de ejecución:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.8
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       55fb7ef977

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.409 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.27 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.27 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.27 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

Error en la ventana de salida:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.6_0.targets(614,5): Error MSB6006: "dotnet.exe" salió con el código 1.`

Comment: Intenta lo siguiente: limpiar la solución, cerrar el Visual Studio, abrir nuevamente el VS y dale un build antes de un publish.

Comment: @fredyfx gracias por responder. Probé lo que me dices, pero sigue el mismo error. Edite la pregunta para añadir un detalle de la pantalla de salida.

Comment: Para servirles, por curiosidad, ¿Tienes instalada alguna otra versión de VS?

Comment: tenia instalada la versión 2019, pero la eliminé. Tengo instalado el VS Code

Comment: Ya veo, y ¿Cómo realizas el publish?

Comment: @fredyfx desde el mismo VS, botón derecho al proyecto, opción "Publicar". Apunto el deploy a un servidor. Pero probé "deployar" a un folder y me tira el mismo error.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138569/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-german-w).

Answer (score 2):

Resuelto: resultaba ser que en el path de la solución había un espacio en blanco en el nombre de una de las carpetas (no necesariamente dentro de la solución). Quité el espacio y se publicó correctamente. Dejo [link](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/26061) de donde saqué la información. Ojala ayude a alguien en el futuro porque desde ayer que estaba con este error y necesitaba resolverlo.

Saludos